# IOS to Instagram API --> Signed Request

Tags: ios, api, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm having some trouble understanding the Instagram API and can't seem to find a clear answer online.  What is the difference between Server-side flow and Implicit flow in terms of security?  I understand there is an additional step for exchanging a code for a token when using Server-side.

I am in the middle of developing an IOS app that uses the server-side flow.  I am storing the client-secret within the IOS app itself and am not using an actual web server for any part of my requests.  Does this method pose any security issues as the API states: "You should never ship your client secret onto devices you don’t control".  Do all IOS apps using the server-side flow have a matching server side component or am I missing something here?

The method above is working for me and I am able to access the instagram API.  However, I am now running into the 30 like per hour limit and want to figure out how to lift this.  I understand that I need to send a signed request to the API using X-Insta-Forwarded-For header.  Can this be done within Swift/Objective-C?  I am having a hard time find a method for sending this information.  The closest I have come to an answer is in the following post: [Instagram Signed API Call from iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333176/instagram-signed-api-call-from-ios)

Can this be done?  Thanks for the help!