# 100 photos to like in Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram-api

I am using Instagram api to like photos but unfortunately it allow only 30photos to like i have used signed api. I have also set the header `X-Insta-Forwarded-For` but still it allow only 30 photos to like 
 **"doc. say 100 photos to like"**
also check This url [Click here](http://instagram.com/developer/restrict-api-requests/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: have u used the explicite authentication flow to get users token ?

Comment: Check this answer for the help http://stackoverflow.com/a/26374462/2098690